# Can't run MonoTouch app in iOS Simulator running iOS v3.2

Tags: ios-simulator, xamarin.ios

I've got a MonoTouch app that I want to test on the simulator with OS version 3.2, but the only options on my Project->iPhone Simulator Target are for iPhone and iPad Simulator 4.2. How

How do I get it so I can test on the simulator with different OS versions?

Here's some relevant info:

```
Minimum OS version in Project Options->iPhone Build: 3.0 
MonoTouch version: 3.2.4  
MonoDevelop version: 2.4.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple doesn't allow it in the simulator.  You have to always test on latest and greatest in simulator, or you buy some ipod touches that you run different version on.

http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-1080867.html